# Cordova plugins error in package after ID change

Tags: android, cordova, sapui5

I have created the project in Cordova using the CLI. And after the [plugins are moved to npm registry](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html), whenever I add the plugin to my Cordova project, it is showing the error:

[image: screenshot with error]

Can any one please help either in renaming the default convention of Cordova packages from `org.apache.cordova.camera` to `cordova-plugin-camera`?

I need to solve the issue for platform Android!

Comment: try with direct install from git. if possible.

Comment: How can this be done friend can you please explain the procedure I am not aware of how this is done

Comment: Error 404 not found ,I have updated my npm and after that I am getting error on my org.apache.cordova.whitelist and also on org.apache.codova.camera what is the solution to it..

Comment: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git`

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html says that the plugins changed their IDs can you please suggest how this can be done.All of our core plugins have changed their IDs from org.apache.cordova.* to cordova-plugin-*. like in this manner..

Comment: Have you tried above command which I have given u last

Comment: Yes ,But I is giving error..like..git command line not installed and few other error code.

Comment: Install git command line tools

Comment: Tried the one as suggested but it is not working even when I am not adding the plugin for white list it is getting added in any of the cordova project can you please help me regarding this using the above shared link.......

Comment: Is git is installed in your system?  You can check it by typing 'get' in command line. Which OS u use windows or Mac?

Comment: Windows I am using ,and the development platform is as fallows IDE :Eclipse Juno;
AVD:ARM(armeabi-v7a)
Android Device:4.4.2;

Comment: Do u know how to setup GIT on windows ? Go through some guide for it. And setup it first.

Comment: The path is set for the GIT and the system variable looks like C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd.

Comment: Now try this `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git`

Comment: Thanks dear friend AmorByte..It Worked fine..Thanks a lot..:)

Comment: Glad it works for you Yamini, Now i do expect one thing from you. we both have created so many comments so I will remove my comments and also expect that you will also remove your comments. and after that could you please post an answer to this question step by step how you resolve it. so it may help other community members and freshers. I am indian developer and always love to help anyone specially Indians.

Comment: Amorbytes For sure I would like to do that as an favor for you ,the thing is I did it by simple uninstalling and upgrading my cordova to the latest available by the npm using node.js the version I used for node.js is v0.12.2 and the referring to the git repo of purple cabbage.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question. @Yamini If it reopens, please add an answer and accept it to guide future readers finding a solution

Comment: @Yamini Since the question is reopened now, could you add a proper solution as an answer? That would help future readers.